# Dynamically divide flexbox content into pages

Tags: pagination, flexbox

I'm looking for a handy way of converting a long flexbox div into multiple pages, probably with help of jQuery.

```
<body>
  <div class="flexbox">
    dynamic amount of differently sized elements
  </div>
</body>
```

Please notice that the flexbox is of dynamic width based on the width of the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

I've put together a little demo for you. Giving the container a flex display didn't seem to accomplish anything, so I removed that from my demo. The demo works by moving an `active` class around a bunch of `<section>` elements, each representing a page in your hypothetical app. The CSS negation rule hides all `<section>`s not containing the `active` class.

```js
var button          = document.querySelector('button'),
    btnClickHandler = function() {  
      var activePage     = document.getElementsByClassName('active')[0],
          getNextSibling = function getNextSibling(el) {
            var nextSibling = el.nextSibling;
            
            while (nextSibling && nextSibling.nodeType !== 1) {
              nextSibling = nextSibling.nextSibling
            }
            
            if (nextSibling === null)  {
              nextSibling = document.querySelector('.container section:nth-of-type(1)');
            }
            
            return nextSibling;
          },
          nextPage      = getNextSibling(activePage);
      
      activePage.classList.remove('active');
      nextPage.classList.add('active');
    };

button.addEventListener('click', btnClickHandler)
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla);

body, button {
  font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;  
}

.container {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.container section {
  padding: 1.5em;
  transition: 0.5s;
  will-change: transform;
  transform: translateY(0);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 15px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.container section:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.container section:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
}

.container section:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}

.container section:not(.active) {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-10em);
}

button {
  margin: 0 auto 1em;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  border-radius: 28px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 17px 10px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  transition: 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  will-change: transform, box-shadow;
}

button:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  box-shadow: 0 27px 14px -14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transform: translateY(-2px);
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

* section :last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="page-container">
  <section class="active">
    <h1>Page 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium nostrum perferendis culpa harum nobis illum eos inventore architecto sequi dolorem. Laboriosam non nam sequi tenetur dicta! Numquam optio perspiciatis, consequatur?</p>    
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1>Page 2</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium nostrum perferendis culpa harum nobis illum eos inventore architecto sequi dolorem. Laboriosam non nam sequi tenetur dicta! Numquam optio perspiciatis, consequatur?</p>    
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1>Page 3</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium nostrum perferendis culpa harum nobis illum eos inventore architecto sequi dolorem. Laboriosam non nam sequi tenetur dicta! Numquam optio perspiciatis, consequatur?</p></section>
</div>

<button aria-controls="page-container">
  Change page
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it's not quite what im looking for as I won't know the amount of content or the size of the content when I write the code and therefor won't be able to devide it into sections. Thanks anyway for an awesome Demo :)

Comment: What you're exactly asking for is not possible at this point in time.